# How to make a calculation only once after all move for a step (or just befor score calculation begin )

Tags: optaplanner

Working on task assigning problem with chained variabale。
As there is pinned task (Pinned Entity) for some Employee ,  "the ture task sequence" for every Employee is not the chained variabale， but have to sequence the task by starttime on every Employee .
To avoid repeated sequence calculation ， is there any method to do a process only once after all move for a step (or just befor score calculation,and then all score calculation can use that reslut ) .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [shadow variables](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ENKHGBMDaCM).